# How to convert range to text/string in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I was experimenting with `OFFSET` function and I wanted to check the result of that function - how can I do that?

I'd expect I can somehow print the range, but I found no way to do so.

`=OFFSET(A1,0,0)` returns value in that cell

`=to_text(OFFSET(A1,0,0))` return value formatted as text

Maybe I do not need the text/string, I was googling for coloring and also seems impossible...

Conditional format is not accepting range as `=OFFSET(A1,0,0,3,2)` too...

**edit:**

The sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u4GTKZEuNVA0tMG26YeiKD7bJzmGzmF2DFY_-N76tTM/edit?usp=sharing).

I didn't know how it works (I had to try and fail), it just was not clear from [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en).

I'm expecting `A1:B3` or similar for `=OFFSET(A1,0,0,3,2)`...

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheet you are working on? Also, please provide expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array formula since you are trying to convert multiple cell/range to text. In this case, try using the formula below:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT(OFFSET(A1, 0, 0, 3, 2)))
```

This resulted to:

[image]

Comment: `to_text` not needed, but this is so far closest to what I'm looking for ;-)

Comment: It's only one week and I already used this so many times... This is the best way (I know) how to debug dynamic formulas (=those with offset used).